# Door lever sticks down

Tags: lock, front-door

My new entry door uses a Baldwin La Jolla handle set with interior lever. After the pro installer completed their work I was disappointed to find that the interior lever likes to stick in the down position. You have to force it back to level. It does not stick in the up position. (This is not a multipoint lock so there’s no particular reason to pull up on the lever but that’s the observation.) there’s no sticking when using the thumb lever on the outside.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: why don't you let the *pro installer* worry about that?

Comment: Belt and suspenders.

Comment: Either the shaft is not exactly perpendicular, or it's snagging on the hole, or it's desperately short on lube. Installer is responsible for sorting that out, should have checked operation before he left.

Comment: Try WD40ing it while cranking down and back up.